# How to implement SSL Handshake between Kafka-connect rest api's

Tags: ssl-certificate, apache-kafka-connect

How to implement SSL on the kaka-connect rest api's (POST /connectors), (GET /connectors), (DELETE /connectors/(string:name)

It is required as, whenever there is request for the rest api's from client, then it should be accessed through a secured layer.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka Connect does not currently (October 2017) support SSL.

As an alternative, you could use something like nginx local to the Connect worker as a proxy to terminate the SSL and forward requests to Connect instead.

Comment: Thanks Robin.. for the help. Actually my aim is to implement SSL in the connect , so that no one can access  to the rest end points to delete/add/modify connectors using curl cmd.                                             So as suggested, will nginx local to the Connect worker as a proxy surve my purpose.